# Prepending to list python

Tags: python, list, sorting, prepend

I have two lists:

```
a = [1,1,1]
b = [[2,2,2],[3,3,3]]
```

I want to prepend `a` on `b` in one line of code to create:

```
result = [[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]]
```

I want to also preserve `a` and `b` during the process so you cannot just do:

```
b[:0] = [a]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just use concatenation, but wrap `a` in another list first:

```
[a] + b
```

This produces a new output list without affecting `a` or `b`:

```
>>> a = [1,1,1]
>>> b = [[2,2,2],[3,3,3]]
>>> [a] + b
[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]
>>> a
[1, 1, 1]
>>> b
[[2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]
```

Answer (score 3):

**solved**

I actually took a swing in the dark and tried

```
result = [a]+b
```

which worked:

```
$ print [a]+b
$ [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]
```

Comment: I got excited by my new found knowledge and repeated it with `[[0,0,0]]+[a]+b` to ensure I wasn't just delirious with the simplicity of the solution. edited to match my Q

Comment: Glad you figured it out on your own too. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `+` operator to concatenate. Neither `a` nor `b` will be modified, as a new list will be created.

```
>>> [a] + b
[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]
```

Comment: that is possibly the fastest reply I've every had! Thanks! solved it at the same time :)

Comment: Actually @MartijnPeters beat me by 12 seconds, so technically *his* was the fastest reply you've ever had :)

Comment: Sorry Cyber; you had the first upvote on the post though. :-)